# about eval statement constructs and delete

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

If I run the following code in google chrome console I get the following results

```
var x = 1;

alert(delete x); // false
```

---

```
eval('var y = 2');

alert(delete y); // true
```

Why in the first example the variable is not deleted and in the second example it is deleted?

Comment: Bonus question: why would you ever need this?

Comment: I can't give you any technical details, but I suspect this is related to JavaScript's "[hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting)" behaviour.  Essentially, variables defined with `var foo;` get special treatment, 'cause the JS engine knows they're there before the function runs.  Variables declared with `eval` aren't recognized, and thus don't get that special treatment.

Comment: You've read http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the Mozilla JS Docs for `delete`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete):

> `delete` is only effective on an object's properties. It has no effect
>   on variable or function names.

The example provided is similar to yours.

```
x = 42;         // creates the property x on the global object
var y = 43;     // declares a new variable, y

delete x;       // returns true  (x is a property of the global object and can be deleted)
delete y;       // returns false (delete doesn't affect variable names)
```

So, why does `alert(delete y);` work? I couldn't nail down the exact answer, but basically you cannot rely on the scope of eval.

I think `eval('var y = 2');` does not get declared as a variable and *is treated as a property*, but I haven't found evidence for that yet other than the results of our tests. I'm going to continue researching to see if I find the exact reason.

Other articles on `eval` weirdness:

- http://wingolog.org/archives/2012/01/12/javascript-eval-considered-crazy
- http://brownplt.github.com/2012/10/21/js-eval.html
- http://blog.rakeshpai.me/2008/10/understanding-eval-scope-spoiler-its.html

---

**EDIT 0**

Based on @Xavier Holt's comment, I looked up hoisting and scope in regards to `eval`. [This scope cheatsheet from Mozilla Dev docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet) had the following:

> **eval may capture assignments, but not var declarations**
>
> eval'd vars hoist normally, so evals may capture assignments similar
>   to with:
>
> ```
> function f() {   {
>     let x = "inner";
>     eval("var x = 'outer'");
>     print(x); // "outer"   } 
> }
> ```

If I'm reading this correctly, then my earlier assumption was right. `eval()` does not evaluate `var` declarations by declaring  a variable. It must create a property or be treated as a property in order for `delete` to work.

Comment: I agree with your assumption. An Active Object is created when executing the function. AO contains every variables declaration as a key-value pair. This is done before the function running any code. So eval's declaration probably doesn't modify the AO, instead by adding a new property.

Comment: `Variables created within the eval context get their [[DontDelete]] attribute set to false (or the ECMA 5 equivalent)` reference from [this](https://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/08/09/variables-vs-properties-in-javascript/)